# Dynamic query with LINQ won't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamic

I've tried a couple of ways to execute a simple query but without success.

```
var result = db.Persons.Where("surname = bob");
```

The above will give the error: *No property or field 'bob' exists in type 'Person'*

```
var result = db.Persons.Where("surname = 'bob'");
```

The above will give the error: *Character literal must contain exactly one character*

Has anyone else had these problems and what did you do?
Isn't Dynamic LINQ suppose to work like this or are there older versions or something?

I've added the `Dynamic.cs` to my project and I'm `using System.Linq.Dynamic`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When doing comparisons you need two `==` and also in order to avoid injection use the following overload:

```
var result = db.Persons.Where("surname == @0", "bob");
```

Also I would recommend you downloading and looking at the [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) provided with the product you are using. Scott Gu has also [blogged](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) about it.

Comment: Is there a dynamic way to do this? If I don't know how many parameters I have?

Comment: @Niklas, yes the second argument is an array, so you could pass as many arguments as you like. Simply put them into a dynamic array.

Comment: you mean like `db.Persons.Where("surname == @0 AND lastname == @1", new string[2] {"bob", "stone"};)`?

Comment: This is a better answer since it prevents SQL injection attacks too. Saving me again Darin ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = db.Persons.Where("surname == \"bob\"");
```

would work, though you should make sure whatever bob really is is properly escaped too.

That said, you would do better to have something like this:

```
String bob = "bob"; // or whatever
var result = from p in db.Persons p
             where p.surname = bob
             select p
```

Comment: The column name is added by the user so I won't be able to use the latter.

Comment: That sounds like it's begging for an injection attack... be very careful!

Comment: Yay! That was the problem, not escaping the value. Big thanks!

Comment: Yep, I'll look into that now.