# How to compare values of some column of string data type with replacing some character with dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to compare values in some column with replacing some character from that column value with help of dynamic linq library

Regular Where statement

```
dbContext.TableName.Where("p=> p." + filterField+ ".Contains(\"" + filterValue+ "\")");
```

What i need

```
dbContext.TableName.Where("p=> p." + filterField+".Replace(\"*\",\"\")"+ ".Contains(\"" + filterValue+ "\")");
```

which will evaluate to

```
dbContext.TableName.Where(p=> p.filterField.Replace("*","").Contains("filterValue"));
```

I am getting exception when i am trying to replace double quotes - [Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278540/dynamic-query-with-linq-wont-work).

Comment: you want to use Replace() to convert "" to " within the string, is that correct?

Comment: yes, similar to that, characters may be different to replace

Comment: kay prashna aahe nikhil bhau...wahh

Comment: @ShrimantBajiraoPeshawe-I :  Thank you, latkalo ahe hithech 2 - 3 tasa pasun

Comment: @NikhilChavan c# chya chat room madhye jau vichar ki...konihi sangel