# How to search a database using properties of model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have an MVC4 program in which I have a dropdown with a list of all of the properties of a model. I want the user to be able to select which property then type in a string value to the textbox to search. The issue is I can't dynamically change the query with the value of the dropdown.

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString, string searchFields)
    {
        var selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var first = db.BloodStored.First();
        foreach(var item in first.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem(){ Text = item.Name, Value = item.Name});
        }
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> enumSelectList = selectListItems;
        ViewBag.SearchFields = enumSelectList;

        var bloodSearch = from m in db.BloodStored
                          select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            PropertyInfo selectedSearchField = getType(searchFields);
            string fieldName = selectedSearchField.Name;

            //Dynamic Linq query this is how it needs to be set up to pass through linq.dynamic without exception
            bloodSearch = bloodSearch.Where("x => x." + fieldName + " == " + "@0", searchString).OrderBy("x => x." + fieldName);
            return View(bloodSearch); 
        }
        return View(bloodSearch);
    }
```

Here is my getType method

```
public PropertyInfo getType(string searchFields)
    {
        var first = db.BloodStored.First();
        foreach (var item in first.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if(searchFields == item.Name)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have updated my code to reflect the working query encase it can help anyone else out.
Here is a link to the post that I found my answer from [Dynamic query with LINQ won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278540/dynamic-query-with-linq-wont-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the Dynamic.cs library. you can find it here as well as examples. You can then create your where clauses dynamically.

[dynamic.cs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: +1 I was not aware of the Linq Dynamic Query library.

Comment: I can not for the life of me get the query to do what I want it to do. I'm not sure exactly how it works and it's limited examples don't know too much. I have enclosed my query above if you could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the where function is just like conditionals you should use "==" oh and you need to use the correct lambda syntax.

Comment: bloodSearch = bloodSearch.Where("x => x." + fieldName + " == " + searchString).OrderBy("x => x." + fieldName);

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as before but it seems to be searching only throught the column names and not the actual data. I'm getting a ParseError (No property or field 'Smith' exists in type 'BloodStoredModel') Smith is just one of the names in the database.

Comment: can you create a new string or stringbuilder and evaluate the string before adding it to the where clause and debug to capture what is coming back and post it?

Comment: Ok let me try that now.

Comment: Still the same issue. I have updated my code in the above post.

Comment: k when you debug can you get the actual string being used in the where with the actual values?

Comment: No I realized that the string was being taken as a type. So that "x => x.donorLastName == Smith" was being used when what I wanted was "x => x.donorLastName == 'Smith'" but in linq.dynamic you need to pass it as "x => x.donorLastName == @0","Smith"

Answer (score 0):

you could build the expression yourself.

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp);
}
```

stole this from a post by Marc Gravell.